# Regex equation selects surrounding characters

Tags: regex

I have the following text

```
Cool Title Here 12345
Other title here 13455
```

That I want to turn into this using Atom's find and replace

```
Cool Title Here, 12345
Other title here, 13455
```

My goal is to select the space between the end of a word and the start of a number. My first instinct is this statement

```
[A-Za-z][\s][0-9]
```

However that also selects the last letter and the first number which is not good for this replacement as I would loose data.

How would I accomplish finding the space inbetween two sections using pure Regex

Answer (score 1):

You can capture the letter and the number, and in the replacement, use back reference to add them back:

So specify the pattern:

```
([A-Za-z]) ([0-9])
```

In the replacement:

```
$1, $2
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with the specifics of Atom regular expression processing but some Googling suggests these general regex techniques should work:

You could use \b to identify the word boundary of the preceding word (without capturing it).

You can use (?=\d) to look ahead to the digit without capturing.

so for your example:

```
\b\s(?=\d)
```